# ng-repeat with dynamic list name

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

In my controller, I create a dynamic name of a list of years depending on the index/uuid/id of the selected row of an ng-table that generated this list.

```
vm["years"+id]= getYears();
```

I want to call this list in a ui-select
So, I want to have sth like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="params.filter()[name]" theme="bootstrap">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'all' | translate}}">{{$select.selected}} </ui-select-match> 
<ui-select-choices
    class="duplicate-dropdown-small" scrolly="ctrl.addToLimit()"
    repeat="option in ctrl.years{{ ctrl.id }} | filter: $select.search">
<div ng-bind-html="option"></div>
</ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
```

That works for ng-table but in the case of repeat, I got the following error

> Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected

Is there any way to get the dynamic list name that I want?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: You can't use interpolation inside an angular expression. Use `ctrl['years' + ctrl.id]`. Just as you're doing in your JS code.

Comment: Thank very much! That works! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{invalid: item.isValid{{$index}} == false}"
```

item.isValid0 == false

item.isValid1 == false

...